# How to get data from arraylist

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

i have to add data to like this

```
Dim input() As String = {xP_PHRCODE, xP_PHREQ, xP_PHRFREQ, xP_PHRLABLE, xP_PHRNAME, xP_PHRQTY, xP_PHRUOM, xp_PHRTOTALPRICE}
ListOrder.Add(input)
ListOrder.IndexOf(i, 0).ToString
```

and add it to arraylist " ListOrder.Add(input) "

and this is my data in arraylist for exemple =  0,0 0,1 0,2 ..... 1,0 1,1 1,2 .......

and i want to get data from array list like  ListOrder(0,1).toString .How get data in array list like this or how to specific position i, j in arraylist ?

Thank you so much

Comment: *How to get data from array list?* By using this formula: `l.Item(n)` where `l` is the array list and `n` is the zero-based index of the element to retrieve.

Comment: it still error about out of range.Because arraylist is 2d now i count row to check it tell 2 and first row have 8 data and now how to get all data from first row and second row

Comment: does your `input()` contains `0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2` ??

Answer (score 0):

In your case i don't know why your using an `ArrayList`, Because if you want to get an item in certain position in your `input()` you can simply use the following

```
Dim input() As Integer = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2}
Dim itemInPositionIn3 As Integer
itemInPositionIn3 = input(3)

'Result: itemInPositionIn3 = 1
```